# Code is executed despite checking for isset() with $_POST in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to check whether the user inputted values match the ones that I defined. For this I created a `<form>` with the method `POST`. Since I am just trying the code out I added a action attribute which references to the same `value.php` page. Then I want the page to `echo` whether the values match back to me. I've encountered a strange issue which I've read about in another post on Stack Overflow but I still don't quite understand as to why this happens.

This is the code for the `<form>` which is the content of the `value.php` file :

```
<form action="value.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="fruit" placeholder="FRUIT HERE"><br>
    <input type="text" name="vegetable" placeholder="VEGETABLE HERE">
    <button type="submit">CHECK</button>
</form>
```

In the same file `value.php` above the `<form>` I have the following PHP code :

```
<?php

$db_fruit = 'apple';
$db_vegetable = 'tomato';

if (isset($_POST['fruit']) && isset($_POST['vegetable'])) {
    $fruit= htmlentities($_POST['fruit']);
    $vegetable = htmlentities($_POST['vegetable']);
    if (!empty($fruit) && !empty($vegetable)) {
        if ($fruit == $db_fruit && $vegetable == $db_vegetable) {
            echo 'The values do match.';
        } else {
            echo 'The values do not match.';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Because of the `isset();` function in the PHP code I would expect the `echo` to not be executed unless the user clicks on the `<button>` with `type="submit"`. The code works however if wrong values are in-fact provided and the `echo 'The values do not match.';` gets executed the `echo` does not disappear even after the page is refreshed despite accepting the `Confirm form resubmission` warning and clicking `Continue`. How can I make it so that the `echo` would not appear on page refresh and the page would appear "brand new"?

I should also point out that preferably I am looking for a solution that does not require the use of JavaScript.

Comment: But how do you want to user continue after insert wrong data? You can insert a button "try again" with a link to value.php. So, when user click on button the page reload without resubmit the form and the echo it's not showing

Comment: "Confirm form resubmission" resubmits the form with the previously entered input. To double check, you can try echoing the params you are receiving from PHP

Comment: Anis R, oh I see. I got confused because some websites do have this popup and then on reload all the content is usually lost. This let me to believe that the data actually gets cleared on resubmission.

Comment: The use of `htmlentities` will potentially alter the result - as this does not output the POSTed data why have this?

Comment: I read that it prevents HTML injection attacks by converting the HTML into pure text.

Comment: if you are not printing out the data then not much help

Comment: It would help prevent such attacks but since you never show the data again it isn't relevant. Only use it at the time when you actually output the data into a HTML document

Comment: ADyson I see thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Its exactly the same code that you post here, i merged 2 different parts, you need to prevent form resubmit on refresh for this case so i added javascript between script tags. Also, changed the logic a bit, in my opinion collecting texts going to be echo ' ed in an array, and echoing them together is better approach, but it does not change much. You can also try last version by including script.

```
<?php

$db_fruit = 'apple';
$db_vegetable = 'tomato';

$result = array();

if (isset($_POST['fruit']) && isset($_POST['vegetable'])) {
$fruit= htmlentities($_POST['fruit']);
$vegetable = htmlentities($_POST['vegetable']);
if (!empty($fruit) && !empty($vegetable)) {
    if ($fruit == $db_fruit && $vegetable == $db_vegetable) {
        $result[] = 'The values do match.';
    } else {
        $result[] = 'The values do not match.';
    }
}
}

if (!empty($result)) {
foreach ($result as $val) {
echo "$val";
}
}

?>

<script> //this part will not allow form resubmit on refresh !
if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
}
</script>

<form action="" method="POST"> //because php code is on same file action empty 

<input type="text" name="fruit" placeholder="FRUIT HERE"><br>
<input type="text" name="vegetable" placeholder="VEGETABLE HERE">
<button type="submit">CHECK</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

The echo still appears with no resubmitting the form? That's strange, maybe your browser still sending the POST clicking Continue...

Whatever, a trick you can apply is to use a session control variable.

Just before the form, but after manage the POST, you define a session variable, giving it a random value, for example:

```
$_SESSION['control'] = rand(100000, 999999);
```

And put that value inside the form as a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['control']; ?>" >
```

Now you can check if sent control match the current one instead of check fruit and vegetable (you can still do that if you want):

```
    if (isset($_POST['control']) && isset($_SESSION['control']
        && $_POST['control'] == $_SESSION['control`]) {
```

Of course, don't forget to start session at the beggining of your script:

```
session_start();
```

That's all.

Comment: was this an answer to a different question?

Comment: It's a solution for his problem.